# Escaping arguments when passing %* from batch script as $args to powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping, cmd

I have a batch script that takes any number of arguments (list of files) and executes a powershell script with the following command structure:

`"%POWERSHELL%" -Command "%SCRIPT%" %*`

`%POWERSHELL%` is the path to `PowerShell.exe`, and `%SCRIPT%` is my powershell script that interprets that receives `%*` as `$args`. The problem is that if I pass in something like the filename `test$file.name`, PowerShell receives `test.name`, presumably because `$file` is interpreted as an empty variable.

Is there a good way to escape each argument with single quotes or backticks from the batch script, or otherwise deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape $ characters before you pass %* to the PowerShell script.

```
set ARGS=%*
set ARGS=%ARGS:$=`$%
"%POWERSHELL%" -Command "%SCRIPT%" %ARGS%
```

Comment: Works like a charm - I had no idea about that colon notation!

Comment: Would the carrot `^` work as well? or is the left-quote a special character in powershell?

Comment: @hayk.mart: `%VAR:S1=S2%` replaces strings in variables, see `help set` for more details.

Comment: @JamesK: No, the caret character (`^`) won't work, because it escapes characters for `cmd.exe`. The OP needs to escape the `$` character for PowerShell, so he needs to use the PowerShell escape character. That's what the backtic (`) is.

Comment: In my case, I only needed to escape dollar signs, due to inner classes of java files having $ separators. In general, are there other symbols that would cause problems in this scenario, such as @^?& type characters?

Comment: I'd say you should escape at least @, &, parentheses and curly brackets. Not sure about anything else.