# Passing custom Java properties with period in name when using PowerShell in Windows 10

Tags: java, powershell

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String prop1 = System.getProperty("test.prop", "missing");
    System.out.println("test.prop: " + prop1);
    
    String prop2 = System.getProperty("otherprop", "missing");
    System.out.println("otherprop: " + prop2);
    
    String cmd = System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
    System.out.println("cmd: " + cmd);
}
```

I invoke the built jar using PowerShell:

```
> java -jar TestApp.jar -Dtest.prop=value1 -Dotherprop=value2
test.prop: missing
otherprop: missing
cmd: TestApp.jar -Dtest .prop=value1 -Dotherprop=value2

> java -Dtest.prop=value1 -Dotherprop=value2 -jar TestApp.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class .prop=value1
```

Why does PowerShell not pass the command line arguments as custom properties to Java and how do I make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass batch arguments with dots into a powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614969/how-can-i-pass-batch-arguments-with-dots-into-a-powershell-script) . TL;DR Use `java --% -Dsomethin.dot ....` with PS

Comment: @Rob, if you look carefully, all the code is posted in the question as text already. The image is an illustration. Closing of the question is inappropriate, neither is the downvote.

Comment: @mlt, I think that might work, too. I was able to solve the problem using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct call is:

```
java  -Dtest.prop=value1 -Dotherprop=value2 -jar TestApp.jar
```

When properties are passed after your jar file name, they are passed as program arguments to your `main` method, instead of being set as system properties.

Comment: I get `Error: Could not find or load main class .prop=value1` when running this.

Comment: I believe it is related to how PowerShell is treating the command.

Comment: This is indeed correct.  I suspect you have a space after `-Dtest`. Please check carefully and remove any accidental white space.

Comment: There are no white spaces there. Screenshot attached to the original question.

Comment: There is no space between **-Dtest** and **.prop=value1**. You are looking at value of `System.getProperty("sun.java.command")`, which does have a space. That's why I am asking this question. The command itself has no space in it.

Comment: Can you run that on the normal windows command line... or try `java "-Dtest.prop=value1" "-Dotherprop=value2" -jar TestApp.jar`?

Comment: `java "-Dtest.prop=value1" "-Dotherprop=value2" -jar TestApp.jar` did the trick. It always worked well on command line.

Comment: Then your terminal is playing smart. Seems that it's somehow pre-processing commands. Sorry, I know little about Windows and PowerShell