# When running maven commands from the command line, why is it sometimes necessary to use quotes around the parameter values and sometime not?

Tags: java, maven, double-quotes

I am working with some people on a basic Java project. The POM files are exactly the same. But when I run the maven command, for example:

```
mvn test -Dtest=ExampleTest -DexampleImplementations=com.company.somename.SomeClass
```

It runs fine.

But when some others run the same command it produces errors and won't run. When they change the command to have quotes around the parameter values:

```
mvn test -Dtest=ExampleTest -DexampleImplementations="com.company.somename.SomeClass"
```

It runs fine.

My questions are:

1. Why the quotes are needed sometimes in the command line and sometimes not?
2. Is it best practice to use quotes, and why?

Other notable factors are that we have the same version of maven and the same jdk version. Though I believe the person that it is failing for is using Windows and I am using Mac.
Additionally, this does not have to do with the values having spaces.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the command shell that you use. Are you using a different operating system than those teammates?

Comment: Are those examples representative of the two scenarios? Typically, an argument needs to be quoted in order for the parser to consider an argument with spaces as a single argument, rather than 2+ arguments (depending on how many spaces there are).

Comment: Yes. We are using a different operating system

Comment: Yes. This is representative of the two scenarios. The arguments do not have spaces.

Comment: Are there any characters other than letters and dots in the value you're putting the quotes around?  (And if the answer is no, then I have no clue what's going on, because dots without quotes work fine for me in Windows)

Comment: Apparently powershell splits the arguments not only at whitespaces but dots too.

Comment: The only characters are letters and dots.

Comment: @maraca I forgot about that. It's been a while since I've had to pass an argument with dots to Java (or any program), but I now remember having to surround them with quotes when using PowerShell.

Comment: @maraca if you post that as an answer, I will upvote you.

Comment: Here's another one, they say `,`, `;` and `=` are delimiters too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614969/how-can-i-pass-batch-arguments-with-dots-into-a-powershell-script I found it an interesting question, but I don't know enough about powershell, would need official link.

Comment: I think a good principle is that if your commands have to be compatible with PowerShell, you should use quote marks around anything that's not just letters and numbers.  Who knows what the makers of PowerShell are going to break in the next release?

Comment: Yes. Sounds like this is an issue with passing arguments with dots via powershell. Marking it as a duplicate seems fair. Though, I didn't think to look for powershell commands when I asked this question. How would a person know to think about powershell specifically? It also doesn't come up as a suggestion when asking this question. So personally think an answer would be more appropriate. But I'll leave it up to you guys.

Comment: Since no one has answered this question, and it seems the problem really is related to PowerShell and the way it handles periods/dots, I'm closing this question as a duplicate. Part of the reason closing as a duplicate exists is to refer people to the solution despite (potentially radically) different phrasing of the question.

Comment: Note I was going to try and answer this question myself, but I couldn't find anything official related specifically to `.` in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3). Maybe there's something in other parts of the documentation, or maybe I just missed something. But I didn't feel comfortable adding an answer as, without more specific documentation, I don't think I can add anything more that the duplicate doesn't already cover.